# Formal definition of a mapping confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

This is rather basic introductory to algebra stuff but I don't seem to understand the formal definition of a mapping, here is what it says in my notes:

by a mapping/function $f: A \to B$ we mean a subset $f \subset A \times B$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\forall a \in A$, $\exists b \in B$, s.t. $(a,b) \in f$
2. $(a,b) \in f$ and $(a,b') \in f \Rightarrow b = b'$

I have a few problems with this:

firstly, I know the definition of $A\times B$ (well, I know what it is) but what does it really mean? I understand all the other set operations, just not this one. My book defined it as this $A\times B = \{(x,y) | x\in A \wedge y\in B \} = \{(x,y) | P_A(x) \wedge P_B(y) \}$ but I don't particaly know what it means, it looks very similar to $A \wedge B$.

Secondly, what does it mean by a subset of f in $A\times B$?

Thirdly, is $(a,b)$ an ordered set? Not really sure about this notation either.

If anyone could clear this up - thank you

Comment: What are $P_A(x)$, $P_B(y)$, and $A\wedge B$?

Comment: It just states that it's the predicate of A and B - $A\wedge B = \{x|P_A(x) \wedge P_B(x) \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets use a concrete example to try to understand the definition. Just take A and B to be the real numbers, for now. Then $A \times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers, so it's just a plane. You can think of the set $f \subset A \times B$ as the graph of the function $f$.

Property #1 says that every point $a \in A$ has some point of the graph that is above it.

Property #2 says that if there are two points above some $a \in A$, then these two points must be the same.

So, in summary, #1 and #2 say that every $a \in A$ has exactly one point of the graph that is above it. The vertical height of this point is what we typically denote by "$f(a)$".

This is just an example, so you can't use it to prove any general theorems, but it might help you understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)$ is an *ordered pair* of elements $a$, $b$, or, a sequence of length $2$, if you prefer. Usually in ZFC set theory $(a,b)$ is defined as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (which exists by the pair axiom), which has the most important property of ordered pairs that
$$(a,b)=(c,d) \iff (a=c\,\land\, b=d)$$
Then, $A\times B$ is the set of *all* ordered pairs of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. 
 (For finite sets, we have $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|$ where $|S|$ denotes the number of elements of set $S$.)

A subset $R$ of $A\times B$ is also called a (binary) *relation* between sets $A$ and $B$, and it contains *some* pairs $(a,b)$. For example, the equality relation ('$=$') on a set $A$ can be considered as the diagonal relation $\{(a,a)\mid a\in A\}\,\subseteq A\times A$.

A relation $F\subseteq A\times B$ is called a *function*, if *for each* $a\in A$ there is *exactly one* $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in F$. When $F$ is regarded as a *mapping*, the unique $b$ which satisfies $(a,b)\in F$ is considered the *image* of $a$ *under* $F$. 
(The usual notations like $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\ F(a):=a^2$ or $F:a\mapsto a^2$ can be translated into the language of set theory as $F=\{(a,a^2)\mid a\in \Bbb R\}$.)

Comment: I think writing $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ will confuse the OP more than help.

Comment: Let the OP concentrate on the '*most important property* of ordered pairs' instead.